# Does macOS Sierra support the new iMessage effects

Tags: messages, macos

I have the macOS Sierra final beta, but I seem to be unable to send or receive the new iMessage effects.

Such as the Invisible Ink:

[image: Invisible Ink]

Is it possible to view these effects on macOS Sierra currently? And if it is, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sierra doesn't support all the effects from iOS.  I don't have a definitive list from Apple and I haven't seen one on their site.

On my Sierra I'm missing all the backgrounds and text effects.  I can see any stickers sent to me.

Comment: Also, digital touch message don't appear, nor is there even any mention that they were sent. Tapbacks are converted to text: "Laughed at handwritten message" for instance

Answer (score 1):

There is a mySIMBL plugin I helped write that allows you to send messages with all the effects.

https://github.com/w0lfschild/iMessageParity

You won't be able to see them on your Mac but if you send it to a device on iOS they will.